# How could I redirect nginx request based on the URL

Tags: nginx

I have 3 app servers which are handled by `nginx` server.

```
upstream he {
    server h1.abc.example.com;
    server h2.abc.example.com;
}
```

How could I redirect requests request based on the some header value.Eg

- `abc-h1.abc.example.com` should go to server `h1.abc.example.com`
- `def-h1.abc.example.com` should go to server `h2.abc.example.com`

where `-h1.abc.example.com` is going be same for all requests

Comment: While technically it is a header value (`Host` header), these are destination domain names, which can be implemented easier than a generic header matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way to do this would be with the `server_name` directive in multiple `server` blocks.  Example:

```
server {
    server_name abc-h1.example.com;
    proxy_pass http://h1.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name def-h1.example.com;
    proxy_pass http://h2.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Obviously if you're not using NGINX as an HTTP proxy then replace `proxy_pass` with whatever directive is appropriate: `fastcgi_pass`, `uwsgi_pass` etc.